# Python: How to duplicate element in list when element matches substring

Tags: python-2.7, list

```
a = ['dog','cat','frog']

b = 'cat'
```

How can I return:

```
c = ['dog','cat','cat','frog']
```

I have tried locating the index of `'cat'` in the original list, and then inserting `'cat'` in the next spot, but the loop is running continuously and never ends. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to insert a new `cat` for every `cat`, or just the first one?

Comment: Take a.New list C and Loop the list A and keep on adding elements to list C and wherever something matches with list B, add 2 entries of that element. Finally, you will have the desired result in list C

Comment: every 'cat' is what I am after. ty

Comment: my mistake was the item I had just inserted, that was being counted. thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy` to find where your value is and then insert in the next index.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(["dog", "cat", "frog"])
b = "cat"

idx = np.where(a == b)[0] + 1
new_a = np.insert(a, idx, b)
```

`np.where` will find all the indices where "cat" occurs.  Adding one to those indices will move to the next location in the array.  Calling `np.insert` will append a new value, "cat", at each of those indices.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `while` loop to loop over the list even as it changes size.  That also allows us to better control where we are in the list with an explicit index

```
a = ['dog','cat','frog']

b = 'cat'

index = 0

while index < len(a):
    if a[index] == b:
        a.insert(index, b)
        index += 1  # Skip item we just inserted
    index +=1

print(a)
# ['dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'frog']
```

Comment: ahhh. thank you for this. my mistake was leaving off "index +=1" to skip the just inserted item. Thank you!